# How to convert cftime to unix timestamp?

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, python-xarray, netcdf4

I am looking for some convenient way to convert time in cftime format available in netcdf files to unix timestamp(ms), what is a suitable way to do this without several `for` loops, of extracting date and time string followed by `datetime` type conversion in python, and few other steps to finally get to unix timestamp(ms). While working with array of time values, it's really daunting to use several `for` loops to seemingly simple operation.

If there is any library or functionality available within `cftime` or `datetime` module, i would highly appreciate.

Here is the output of my initial data in `cftime` format:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'time' (time: 227)>
array([ 107. ,  129.5,  227.5, ..., 7928. , 7958.5, 7989. ], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) float32 107.0 129.5 227.5 ... 7.928e+03 7.958e+03 7.989e+03
Attributes:
bounds:         time_bounds
calendar:       gregorian
axis:           T
standard_name:  Time
long_name:      Time
Units:          days since 2002-01-01T00:00:00
```

When I used `xarray.decode_cf(dataset)`, the array is shown but it is still random, and I am not able to figure out what these numbers mean.

Here is a sample array after `xarray.decode_cf()` operation:

`[107.   129.5  227.5  258.   288.5  319.   349.5  380.5  410.   439.5 470.   495.5  561.5  592.5]`

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question in sentence format.

Comment: The question is pretty clear I think, what *might* be missing is an easy-to-copy-and-run [mre]. However, I think the problem here is the "Units" attribute; xarray does not expect this to be title-case; change it to "untis" and it should work. There's an example at the end of [this docs section](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/latest/user-guide/time-series.html#creating-datetime64-data).

Answer (score 0):

Illustrating my comment,

```py
import xarray as xr

# note that "units" must not me title-case:
attrs = {"units": "days since 2002-01-01T00:00:00"}
ds = xr.Dataset({"time": ("time", [107. ,  129.5,  227.5, 7928. , 7958.5, 7989.0], attrs)})

# now we have datetime:
xr.decode_cf(ds)
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (time: 6)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2002-04-18 2002-05-10T12:00:00 ... 2023-11-16
Data variables:
    *empty*

xr.decode_cf(ds).time
<xarray.DataArray 'time' (time: 6)>
array(['2002-04-18T00:00:00.000000000', '2002-05-10T12:00:00.000000000',
       '2002-08-16T12:00:00.000000000', '2023-09-16T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2023-10-16T12:00:00.000000000', '2023-11-16T00:00:00.000000000'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2002-04-18 2002-05-10T12:00:00 ... 2023-11-16

# to get Unix time in ms, we can convert to integer, giving us Unix time in 
# nanoseconds, then divide by 1e6 to get milliseconds:
xr.decode_cf(ds).time.astype(int)//1_000_000
<xarray.DataArray 'time' (time: 6)>
array([1019088000000, 1021032000000, 1029499200000, 1694822400000,
       1697457600000, 1700092800000])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2002-04-18 2002-05-10T12:00:00 ... 2023-11-16
```